# Can I replay République's episodes once completed?

Tags: republique

I am currently playing Camouflaj's game République on PS4 and as the game was released in the format of episodes, I'm wondering if they'll be available as separate content once I've finished the main storyline, in the fashion of TellTale's games. By instance, would I be able to jump directly from the menu to the 4th episode?

I *think* I've heard about a "new episode plus" mode in a YouTube video that I can't seem to find anymore. So, if anyone can provide a definite answer to that question, it would be really useful because this will influence the way I handle the game (well, collectibles mostly).

Comment: The iOS and Steam versions have multiple save slots. If the PS4 does as well, you can create a new save to replay the game.

Comment: The thing is that the game would probably read my progression in order to grant me access to episodes others than the first. I think that by using another save slot (provided the PS4 allows for such a thing, I haven's checked yet), I still would have to "unlock" episodes 2 to 5.